# Playframework : How to share models between different projects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework

I want to share my Models with some other projects, they use the same models but not the same field mappings and constraints. I wonder if there is way to extract annotations from models and use xml configuration instead ? Or other way to achieve this ?

NOTE : I'm using `play 1.3`.

Comment: Play 1.x is using Hibernate as JPA provider, so Hibernate way should work.

Comment: Why not just have a separate shared module?

Answer (score 1):

Last week I were analyzing something like that.

A way to archive this is:

1. generate a library (jar) for each reusable models, defined by annotations or by `orm.xml` files on `META-INF` folder (*but not `presistence.xml`*).
2. In web application project, reference required model libraries and define the `entityManager` using a `persistence.xml` on `META-INF`.

For more information see the [JPA spec](https://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr317/), *6.2 Persistence Unit Packaging*

Other references:

- [JPA - multiple jars defining @Entity objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7442735/jpa-multiple-jars-defining-entity-objects)
- [JPA 2.0: Adding entity classes to PersistenceUnit *from different jar* automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380728/jpa-2-0-adding-entity-classes-to-persistenceunit-from-different-jar-automatic/13756652#13756652)
- https://www.java.net/node/665328

Good luck!

Comment: Can it be done without jars? I've atached sources using build.sbt.