# Adding jpa/hibernate @Entity in submodule in playframework to entity manager to scan

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, playframework-2.0, git-submodules

I have problem with hibernate entity while working with submodules in playframework.

Normally (in single app without submodules) I've used that code:

```
package models;
    @Entity
    public class AppMode {
        public static AppMode getCurrentConfigurationEntry() {
            return JPA.em().find(AppMode.class, 1L);
        }
    }
```

But now I have to tell hibernate entity manager to scan submodules models, cause I'm getting an error:

```
[IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: AppMode]
```

My model class in submodule is in package:

```
package models.common;
```

I've already tried:

```
        return JPA.em().find(models.common.AppMode.class, 1L);
        return JPA.em().find(common.models.AppMode.class, 1L);
```

but I'm getting the same error:

```
[IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: models.common.AppMode]
```

My question is: How to configure hibernate in play subproject to add submodules models class to classpath at runtime?

I have in both build.sbt files declared libraryDependencies with hibernate.

Should I have persistence.xml file/configuration for each module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to mannually add mapping thought xml persistance file and also using Annotation Mapping: @Entity

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is about JPA configuration. Check this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25623071/2295657) which explains JPA multi-module configuration.

Good luck!

Comment: It dosn't helped me at all. I know I have to somehow tell play framework to scan submodules for entities. But how?

Answer (score 0):

I think Hibernate only scans for JPA Entities inside jar files, and not in classes/ folders for example, or it only scans in the jar with the persistence.xml, or something like that. Here's a solution with pure Hibernate on JavaSE, no Spring: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41845759/377320